# Анатолий - анатольев, but Анатолия - what adjective?

Tags: этимология

From the proper noun Анатолий we can form the possessive adjective анатольев (like in the expression анатольевы стихиры), but from the proper noun Анатолия (i mean the girl's name, not turkish region) how can we form the possessive adjective ? Something like мама - мамин.

Comment: Many thanks, Alex! You saved my day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say *анатольин* instead of *анатолиин*. The reason is that letter *и* tends to get replaced by a soft sign *ь* in possessive forms of nouns when it follows letter *л*, like you demonstrated in your question: *анатолий - анатольев* (not *анатолиев*). Therefore *анатольин* sounds  more natural to me than *анатолиин*.

Also consider that patronymic name derived from *Анатолий* would be *Анатольевич* (masculine gender) or *Анатольевна* (feminine gender), again with the soft sign.

Comment: I'd support your point of view (Наталия - Натальин день): https://novos.mk.ru/social/2020/09/08/natalin-den-chto-mozhno-i-chego-nelzya-delat-8-sentyabrya.html

Answer (score 0):

Marius, the possessive adjective from the female proper noun Анатолия is Анатол**иин**. As from the proper noun Мария — Мар**иин**.